# Qt Creator - LNK1104: cannot open file "glu32.lib"

Tags: windows, qt, opengl, qmake, glu

I am using Qt and Qt Creator and I want to run a test file to see if my Installation is correct or not. I use Windows 8.1 64 bit. I installed the newest Qt OpenGL 64 bit Version for Windows.

I already included the file glu32.lib by doing this in my .pro file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows 

Kits/8.1/Lib/winv6.3/um/x64/ -lGlU32
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Lib/winv6.3/um/x64/ -lGlU32d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um/gl
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um/gl
```

That did not fix it. The file exists in that Folder. Can you help me please?

Comment: do you need quotes around paths with space in qmake?

Comment: I didn't write that. Qt creator itself put this code in my pro file. I added the lib with the user Interface in qt creator.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is case sensitive.

Secondly, you do not need to add the debug marker explicitly, so just write this:

```
LIBS += glu32
```

rather than:

```
LIBS += Glu32d
```

Also, as Martin pointed out in a comment, you better double quote strings containing spaces as follows:

```
-L"$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows"
```

or this if you fancy:

```
-L$$quote($$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows)
```

Furthermore, this does not make any sense as the second branch will never satisfy:

```
win32: ...
else: win32: ...
```

If you do not want to go editing the project file, you can use the QtCreator GUI to add a system library like glu:

[image]

Furthermore, you seem to have 64 bit Qt installed on Windows, but you are trying to use 32 bit glu. Do not do that. Use either 32 bit for both or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 QMAKE_LIBDIR += "glu32_location"
```

to your .pro file, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a project, at the kit selection, only select:

> Desktop Qt 5.4.1 64bit

I had the same problem, then I made a new project without the `32 bit OpenGL Kit` selected and it works fine for me. By default, Qt has both selected.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about the QtCreator IDE, but I got this error when compiling from the command line.  I had to run vcvars32.bat to fix it. Everything compiled fine because the msvc compiler was already in PATH, but linking was the problem.